# Change the link before the image

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

when I write a link to the image so `/sites/all/themes/shifonur/img/category/medical_apparat`
I don't understand why the link before the image changes and don't show image...
Drupal front of text automatically puts taxonomy link
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You shoud add a slash (/) before your URL of the image. So

```
<img src="/sites/all/themes/shinofur/img/category/medical_apparat/apparat_1.png" alt="annapat 1" class="catalog_apparat">
```

Instead of:

```
<img src="sites/all/themes/shinofur/img/category/medical_apparat/apparat_1.png" alt="annapat 1" class="catalog_apparat">
```

Comment: Yep, always use "root relative paths". They are starting with slash sign, telling the browser to start from site root. If not, it will start from current page path and just add image path to path of current page ("relative paths").

Answer (score 0):

Image paths are relative instead of absolute.

Your Browser URL 'drupal.uz/taxonomy/term' is prefixed with the Image paths. You have config path in the Editor in which you are using.

Try using [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) and config, which would help you.